# Div area does not want to show when using object

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm using the following code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">HEADER</div>

    <div id="content-main">
              <object
        classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0"
        id="selfieland"
        width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="movie" value="selfieland.swf">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#D6D6D6">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false">
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="samedomain">
         <PARAM NAME="SCALE" VALUE="default">
        <embed
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
          pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"
          name="selfieland"
          width="100%" height="100%"
          src="Images/selfieland.swf"
          bgcolor="#D6D6D6"
          quality="high"
          seamlesstabbing="false"
          allowscriptaccess="samedomain"
          SCALE="default"
        >
        </embed>
      </object>
        TEST
    </div>
    <div id="footer">©  net - Copyright 2014 - Terms and Conditions</div>
</div>
```

I can see the header but there's a huge gap from the header and the main content section,
and my biggest issue is that the footer div does not show once the Flash loads.
My document was fine with an image. for some reason the Flash is messing it up.

My CSS is as follows:

```
#wrapper {
        width:90%;
        margin:0px;
        border:0px solid #bbb;
        padding:0px;
    }

#header {
        border:0px solid #bbb;
        padding:0px;
        background-image:url("Images/sclogo_01.png");
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height:50px;
        background-position:center;
    }

#content {
        margin-top:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        border:1px;
    }

#content div {
        padding:0px;
        border: 0px;
        float:none;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }

 #content-main {
        margin-left:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }


#footer {
        background-image:url("Images/sclogo_03.png");
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height:50px;
        float:left;
        background-position:center;
        font-size: large;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, are you willing to go back to the drawing board on this one and start again?

I think you should try SWFObject: https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

This example from their documentation looks like it just might do the trick for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContent">
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Download, set up and Modify, give it a go and let me know how it works for you.